# trying to iterate over a string and translate message

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

This a simple exercise, I think I have it right but maybe some minor syntax misunderstanding. Anyone have better way of doing this. Just want to iterate over the string and for each value change if necessary, then reprint string

```
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
message = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."


key = list(alphabet)
message = list(message)


for index, i in enumerate(message):
    if i in key:
        if key.index(i)  == 25:
            message[index] = "b"

        elif key.index(i)  == 24:
            message[index] = "a"

        elif key.index(i) < 24:
            set_value = key[key.index(i) + 2]
            message[index] = set_value

for i in message:
    print i,
```

I have edited the code to provide the final answer to the problem/riddle.

Output:

```
i   h o p e   y o u   d i d n t   t r a n s l a t e   i t   b y   h a n d .   t h a t s   w h a t   c o m p u t e r s   a r e   f o r .   d o i n g   i t   i n   b y   h a n d   i s   i n e f f i c i e n t   a n d   t h a t ' s   w h y   t h i s   t e x t   i s   s o   l o n g .   u s i n g   s t r i n g . m a k e t r a n s ( )   i s   r e c o m m e n d e d .   n o w   a p p l y   o n   t h e   u r l .
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have now? Why do you think there may be "some minor syntax misunderstanding"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: when i print out the letters at the end it only prints

[.]

Comment: @vikingcode then please add that information to your question

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood that isn't valid Python syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
letters = [] # create empty list

for char in message:
    letters = [char] # replace letters with new list, containing only char
```

will leave `letters` as a list with a single element; the last `char` in `message`. If you want the whole of `message` as a list, the minimal fix is:

```
for char in message:
    letters.append(char) # adds to the end of the list, rather than replacing it
```

or you can simply do:

```
letters = list(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the string and add a new character to a "result string" (with the appropriate changes):

```
result = ""

for c in message:
    if c == "k":
        result += "m"
    elif c == "o":
        result += "q"
    elif c == "e":
        result += "g"
    else:
        result += c  # don't need changes, concatenate the same character

print result
```

Comment: True, but I anticipated needing to do more complex things with the string so I decided to put it into a list. 

LOL shit yeah every letter needs to be shifted over twice in the alphabet to correctly solve :)

Comment: @vikingcode in that case, I'd suggest building a dictionary `{old_char: new_char, ...}` rather than umpteen `elif` branches.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use replace:

```
print(message.replace('k','m').replace('o','q').replace('e','g'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the riddle gives you a hint for a more compact implementation - use `maketrans`.

```
message = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

rot2 = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                     'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab')
print(message.translate(rot2))
```

This is for python 3 - python 2 is left as an exercise to the reader :-)